# firebase.json redirect from one domain to another with the same page after /

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to redirect from thisdomain.com/webpage to thatdomain.com/webpage

I've tried using these globs for the source match:

```
/*
/**
*
**
```

This is my current firebase.json:

```
 {
    "hosting": {
    "public":".",
    // Add the "rewrites" section within "hosting"
        "rewrites": [ {
            "source": "/**",
            "destination": "https://thisdomain.com/**"
        } ]
     }
}
```

I want someone who goes to thatdomain.com/webpage to be redirected to thisdomain.com/webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrites are used within a site, they do not rewrite across multiple sites.

If you mapped both domains to the Firebase Hosting project as custom domains, then no additional setup should be required. You *do* need to map each domain/target to the `public` directory though. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#define_hosting_config

Comment: I see, thank you Frank - I very much appreciate your response. Just to confirm, then, I can't redirect to an external website then (a domain hosted outside of Firebase)

Comment: That is indeed not possible with a `rewrite` in the `firebase.json` configuration, as those are literal path rewrites in the same infrastructure. It should be possible with [`redirect` instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects), although I never tried and am not sure how it deals with captures in your rules.

Comment: Your comment helped me 1000%, Frank. You rock. I misunderstood the difference between a rewrite and redirect and had "rewrite" _not_ "redirects" in my json file. So my last question is this: with a redirect, it's not possible to have anything other than a static destination so that I could direct browsers to /webpage on the destination from the source url? Once again - you rock & thank you.

Comment: Yeah, as said: I'm not sure we pass along captured segments. If we don't you can always just host a minimal index.html, and do the redirect client-side. The difference in bandwidth and performance should be minimal.